# How to persist null properties in Azure table storage?

Tags: azure-storage, data-annotations, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory, json-deserialization

I'm trying to download some json data to a SQL DB via Azure data factory v2. I'm storing the data in an Azure table field as an intermediate step. However, some properties in my source json might be null, but I still want to maintain them as columns having null values in my azure table to simplify the column mapping to the SQL DB table later.

I read this in the documentation:

> The Table service does not persist null values for properties. When querying entities, the above property types are all non-nullable. When writing entities, the above property types are all nullable, and any property with a null value is handled as if the payload did not contain that property.

I've tried adding a DefaultValueAttribute like `[DefaultValue(null)]` but that doesn't work.

Also, adding a default value to the property doesn't work

```
public string streetName { get; set; } = "None";
```

Is there a way in which I can still maintain the null properties?

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding, azure storage table itself doesn't have schema.

If in the first row, you insert 1 to columnA, 2 to columnB,
Then in the second row, you insert 3 to columnA, 4 to columnC. 
Then if you try to preview data with ADF or azure storage explorer, you will get null for columnC in the first row, and null for columnB in second row.

So to have that null column, seems you only need have a row with null value for that column.

Another way to avoid this issue: maybe you could consider use azure blob storage  as an intermediate step? ADF supports coping data from azure blob storage to azure sql directly. And azure blob storage can store json files.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But, I need a way to deserialize my source json such that my column values will return a default value if it's null in the source. Also, Blob storage won't work for me as I need to handle duplicate data which is supported by table storage.